# How to set NTP client on RPi-4 to point to a local IP on my lan?

Tags: ntp

I'm putzing with RPi-4 with (I guess) stretch and initially both the NTP= and Fallbackntp= lines of timesyncd.conf are hashed out.  Yet service ntp status shows it soliciting 10 pool servers.  When I set my local lan router on the NTP= line and restart ntp service, nothing changes.  How do I get the Pi4 to use MY NTP server setting and NOTHING ELSE?

Answer (score 3):

NTP servers from `timesyncd.conf` are preceded by ones given by DHCP. Try disabling those using

```
[DHCP]
UseNTP=false
```

in `/etc/systemd/networkd.conf`. Alternatively, try

```
[Time]
NTP=
NTP=myserver
```

in `timesyncd.conf`.

To verify the configuration that is currently in use, you can run

```
timedatectl show-timesync --all
```

Comment: I will look into the DHCP thing, but I have the Pi set to a static IP - don't know if that alone changes things with regard to NTP.  I didn't know that DHCP can also set/provide NTP server information.  In my case, my ER3-lite router is the lan's dhcp and NTP server, so it seems the pi should be using it as I want it to.

Comment: What command line can I use to get the NTP server or server list that the Pi is currently configured to use?

Comment: @PeggySchafer `timedatectl show-timesync --all`